# Is there a way to get more than 1 shop page menu on my site?

Tags: woocommerce

There will be 2 different account types on the site, customer and shop. The product inventories will be coming from API integration. I want to show each "shop" account's product inventories on the shop page of that account. How can accomplish this?

As WooCommerce has no built-in feature to show different inventories based on API responses, I was given the advice to develop a custom plugin to address this process. Are there any other pieces of advice to getting this done?